# Intermediate save and readonly after termination

Tags: orbeon

We have the requirement that users, after terminating the input of a form, can only see the data;  only authorized users can modify the data.
For this purpose we use the following permissions and it works smoothly:
[image: permissions]

Now raised a second requirement.
The users wish the possibility to finish the input of the form in a second moment, so that they don't have to fill in the form entirely after pressing the new button, before they can push the save button.
Because some forms are large and maybe they are in a hurry to catch the bus, or maybe for some answer they have to ask someone else not contactable at the moment.

The idea was to add the save-draft button.
The first save-draft  is OK; the message is *"Draft saved successfully!"*.
But the second save complains:
[image: error in second draft-save]

It seems that the permissions don't differentiate between *save* and *draft-save*, so that also after a draft-save the form data is read-only.

Which possibilities I have to achive this two goals?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`save-draft` process](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/tag-release-2017.1-ce/src/main/resources/config/properties-form-runner.xml#L262) is very much like the regular save (`save-final` process), except that it lets users save data even if the value of some fields is invalid. So, indeed, from the perspective of the permissions, `save-final` and `save-draft` are the same.

What you would really need is the ability for:

1. A process to save the *stage* of the form along with the data. In your case, the stage could be "work in progress" or "submitted".
2. The permissions to be able to depend on that stage, so you can say "users can edit their own data if the stage is work in progress, but can only view it if the stage is submitted".

You can do #1 right now using a hidden field and an [`xf:setvalue()`](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-xforms.html#xfsetvalue) action. But you can't do #2. For that, you would need the workflow feature to be implemented (see [RFE #2256](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2256)), which we hope to be able to complete in 2018. So, you guessed it, the good news is that this is coming, but the bad news is, at least as I write these lines, that it isn't implemented yet.