# How to set a form readonly (how to avoid the stay - leave popup)

Tags: orbeon

We have the requirement that users, after terminating the input of a form, can only see the data; only authorized users can modify the data, see question 
[intermediate save and readonly after termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807346/intermediate-save-and-readonly-after-termination).
The first idea was to use the permission: **owner can read the data**.
This works  smootly : afer saving, in the summary page the form is marked as readonly.
[image: forms marked as readonly]

But there was also the requirement: users must be able to interrupt the input of the form and resume it later.
So in the permissions we had to set that the owner can read and update the data, and we use a field of the form to set the section to readonly.
The *save-final* button sets this field.
We have renamed this button to **FINISH**, and the save-draft button to **intermediate save**.
Clicking *save-final* also makes invisible the save buttons, so the user after clicking this button cannot change anymore the data.
Before clicking FINISH:
[image: before the save]
After clicking FINISH:
[image: after the save]

Selecting  the form in the summary page and choosing *review*  works smootly: the form is opened in view mode.
But clicking in the *created*  or *modified* field  opens the form in edit. And although all form fields are readonly, clicking at the summary button a window "Leave page Stay on page" is shown. I suppose, because of the vars of the database service the form results as a modified page.
[image]

After clicking *leave Page*, in the summary page a new draft form is shown. This draft form only an Administrator can delete. Because the user haven't the permission to delete.
[image]

So the question is:
 is there a possibility to set the form read-only when the user clicks the FINISH button? So that in the summary page the form is marked as read only?
 Or as another option: is there a possibility to disable the columns *Created*  and *Modified*"  in the summary page, so that only the first column in the summary page is clickable?

[Link to the test code](https://gist.github.com/hoila/989563d499d6dbef1a7edda14338dff5)

Many thanks

Comment: How are you making all the fields read-only after users click the "FINISH" button? Are you changing the value of a field somewhere in the data, maybe in a hidden field, then using the value of this field to mark all the sections as read-only?

Comment: Orbeon Forms implementing the "workflow feature" (see [RFE #2256](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2256)) would allow you to implement this scenario. With the workflow feature, you'll be able to attach a *stage* to form data, in your case you'll maybe have `intermediate`  and `finished`, and will be able to have the permissions on the form depend on the current stage. So I'm add a +1 from you on that RFE.

Comment: @avernet   _>How are you making all the fields read-only after users click the "FINISH" button?_  
The save final process sets the field datenOK: `then xf:setvalue( ref="//datenOK", value="true()")`      
and every section uses  this field for the readonly, for example:    
`<xf:bind id="section-55-bind" ref="section-55" name="section-55"   readonly="$datenOK =true()">`         
Next I will experiment with **pointer-events:none;** in css and the property `"oxf.fr.summary.css.custom.uri.*.*"`,   trying to let only the first summary column clickable

Comment: OK, thank you for the precision; I suspected you were doing something like this, but wanted to be sure. So the issue is that when you come back to this form, and you're on a `/edit` page, but all the fields are readonly, when you click on the *Summary* button at the bottom of the page, somehow Form Runner thinks the data is "dirty" and asks you if you really want to leave the form without saving.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this by with [this form](http://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/d474c025c86e22af1f5d442adea334a528c7da26). I publish it, go to the [`/new` page](http://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/hoila/readonly/new), enter `42` in the field (which makes section readonly), save, go to the summary page, click on the row, the form opens, and there I can click on the *Summary* button without being prompted to save the data. So it seems that I'm not able to reproduce the issue you're seeing.

Comment: I suspect you're seeing this problem because you have some logic in your form that changes the data, maybe on form load. Is that possible?

Comment: @avernet I had the problem only with forms using a database service. [The test code](https://gist.github.com/hoila/989563d499d6dbef1a7edda14338dff5) contains a database service to populate a dropdown. Using this code the problem should be reproducible.  Feedback: I have good news :)  I tried the **pointer-events:none;** with firefox, and the first column of the summary page remained clickable, and all the following columns were disabled. So the users have to use the review button to see the form data and the form opens in view mode. Now I will try with IE and give than a feedback.

Comment: @avernet feedback:  I inserted  in the custom summary css the lines: 
`.orbeon .fr-summary-table-div td a,
.orbeon .fr-summary-table-div th a {
  pointer-events: none;
}`
and tested it with firefox 52, IE 11 and chrome 62, and it works in all tree browsers: only the first column is clickable.
Unfortunately I had a thought error because of the intermediate save. 
After the draft-save there is no button to continue the input.
Actually to open the form in edit I have to open it with *review* and change in the browser address `/view/` with `/edit/`.  
Is there an edit button in orbeon?

Comment: I see: you are calling a service on form load, and that service sets an itemset. The issue is that itemsets are stored as part of the form data, so that action alone could mark your data as dirty. Should it mark the data as dirty, if the user hasn't changed anything in the form? I can think of supporting arguments for both possible answers to that question.

Comment: Mmmh… I've created [a form](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/73c016049825e916015f6ab4c0e3a51d) with a dropdown populated from a service on form load. You can paste the source of this form in Form Builder if you want to try this yourself. Publish the form, open the `/new` page, and notice how you can close it right away without seeing the warning message. So I don't seem to be able to reproduce what you're seeing. Can you think of something you're doing differently that would trigger the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: @avernet  I tried to run your code but   until now without luck, because connection refused.  
`2017-11-20 10:08:22,198 DEBUG DefaultClientConnectionOperator  - Connect to httpbin.org:80 timed out. Connection will be retried using another IP address
...
2017-11-20 10:08:29,238 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     xforms-submit-error - Connection refused: connect`

Comment: Maybe http://httpbin.org/ was down when you tried? Can you access the web site from your browser?

Comment: @avernet Today I installed a fresh tomcat-8.5.23 and a fresh orbeon-2017.1.201706222342-CE and retried, but without success.
In the orbeon log is the line
`2017-11-21 08:33:13,882 ERROR XFormsServer  - xforms-submit-error - Connection refused: connect` 
In the browser a window _ICFS-Internet Content Filtering System - Notification_  window opended:
`Web gateway Security
Host Not Resolvable
URL: http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms
Failure Description: Network is unreachable:EnduserException:server state 1:state 8:Application response 502 notresolvable
Contact us if ...blocked webpage
`

Comment: Mmmh… this is really strange; nobody should try to resolve `http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms`. This is just a namespace. Do you have a full exception for this? If you do, would you be able to paste it in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and put the link here?

Comment: @avernet Sorry for the late response - I was occupied trying to make in a repeated section an alternating background. This [orbeon.log](https://gist.github.com/hoila/5194ba3f0bb60d547c98e0e1d727078d/raw/650bebb22af575574487272f4bccb72bc51626a7/gistfile1.txt) is with `<priority value="debug"/>` in log4j.xml, otherwise *orbeon.log* contained only a single entry `ERROR XFormsServer  -       xforms-submit-error - Connection refused: connect `.   In line 8681 I see **Connect to httpbin.org:80 timed out.**  The tomcat release is *apache-tomcat-8.5.23*, the orbeon release is *2017.1.201706222342 CE*

Comment: And are you able to connect to load http://httpbin.org/headers in your browser? Note that I just used this URL because it is a public site that returns some JSON, but if for some reason you can't load it, I hope you can still get the idea from the source.

Comment: @avernet I see  the following answer.  In the answer I note the line **"Connection": "close"**.  Maybe it matters.  ` {
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.5", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
  }
}`

Comment: The value you have for the `Accept` header is interesting: it doesn't show JSON, which makes me suspect you're using an "old" version of Orbeon Forms. What version do you have? If not 2017.1, could you try with that version?

Comment: @avernet I made the test with the orbeon release 2017.1.201706222342 CE,  because CE supports the http services. I have also a  2017.1 PE trial version - used for the tests with oracle. I will repeat the test with the PE.  (Note:  today I saw in the oracle table `orbeon_form_data`  : *<fr:metadata><itemset id="fr36903693d5b5c571afca3f95175cf3752f5da812"><choices xml:lang="de"><item><label>.....* .  In your answer from 17 Nov  you wrote me of this: _The issue is that itemsets are stored as part of the form data, so that action alone could mark your data as dirty _

Comment: I am puzzled by your comment "because CE supports the http services". Orbeon Forms does not support Services & Actions in Form Builder. Or did you want to say something else?

Comment: @avernet My test code used a database service and your sample code  a http service.    In the [database services documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/database-services.html#overview) I read: "*By using database services, a PE feature...*", sentence not present in the documentation of the http services. So I thought I can use your sample  code also with orbeon CE.   I'm happy to have found the second solution; using  the summary page is so friendlier for the users.

Comment: Well… I'm a bit lost here, but I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found as a possibility:

1. Inhibit the edit in the summary page
2. add an edit button to the detail page and associate it with the edit
   action
3. Change the description of the Review button to **Review/Edit**

**to 1)**   I inserted in the custom summary css the lines:
`.orbeon .fr-summary-table-div td a,

.orbeon .fr-summary-table-div th a {

  pointer-events: none;

}`

**to 2)**   Lines added in the *properties-local.xml*:
    Add an edit button to the buttons of the detail page
    `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.view.*.*"   value="summary edit pdf"/>`
    Add the edit process to the edit button
    `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.edit.apptest.*"     value="edit"/>`
    Add descriptions to the edit key
    `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.resource.apptest.*.en.buttons.edit" value="EDIT"/>`
    `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.resource.apptest.*.de.buttons.edit" value="Ändern"/>`
    `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.resource.apptest.*.it.buttons.edit" value="Aggiorna"/>`
    Show the edit button only if the input phase isn't terminated
    `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.button.edit.visible.apptest.*">

          //datenOK = false()

 </property>`

Summary page with review/edit button
[image]

Detail page with edit button (because the input phase isn't yet terminated)
[image]

Detail page without edit button (the input phase is already terminated)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the [test code](https://gist.github.com/hoila/989563d499d6dbef1a7edda14338dff5)   was the action: *Run action when the form loads* [image: enter image* description here]
I changed the action in   **Run action when the control appears or changes its value**
and now the popup  page: *stay on page - leave page* appears anymore.
[image]